# Tkinter, get value from toplevel window

Tags: python, tkinter

So, i have two classes, ApplicationWindow is main and LoginWindow is toplevel of main. So i can't return the entered value from toplevel window to main's self.LOGIN and self.PASSW. Looked through SO - found nothing that could help me. Can you help me?

My code:

```
import os
import sys
import tkinter as tk

class ApplicationWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        # print(l,p)
        self.LOGIN = "555"
        self.PASSW = "666"
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry('800x400')
        self.master.title("app")
        self.master.f_app = tk.Frame(self.master).pack()
        self.menuBuild()

        self.b_log = tk.Button(self.master, width=10, text="button").pack()


    def menuBuild(self):
        menubar = tk.Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menubar)

        mainMenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        mainMenu.add_command(label="Login", command=self.login)
        mainMenu.add_separator()
        mainMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.onExit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=mainMenu)


    def login(self):
        self.tl_log = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.login = LoginWindow(self.tl_log)


    def onExit(self):
        self.master.destroy()


class LoginWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("login")
        self.master.f_login = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.master.geometry("300x100")
        self.l_log = tk.Label(self.master, text="mailbox")
        self.l_psw = tk.Label(self.master, text="password")
        self.e_log = tk.Entry(self.master, width=25)
        self.e_psw = tk.Entry(self.master, show="*", width=25)
        self.b_log = tk.Button(self.master, width=10, text="login", command=self.func)
        self.l_log.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.l_psw.grid(row=2, column=1)
        self.e_log.grid(row=1, column=2)
        self.e_psw.grid(row=2, column=2)
        self.b_log.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=2)


    def func(self):
        l = self.e_log.get()
        p = self.e_psw.get()
        if l == "" or " " in l:
            print("not")
        else:
            return l, p
            self.master.destroy()


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    main = ApplicationWindow(root) 
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: no no!  do not inherit from `tk.Tk` if you aren't going to use your objects as `Tk` instances!  It may not be giving you issues now but if you do `super().__init__(master)` like you should with inheritance you would see how it explodes on you.

Comment: also putting `self.master.destroy()` after a return statement means it will never execute, the `return` ends the function.

Comment: It's (arguably) OK to have _one_ class inherit from `Tk`, but you definitely shouldn't have more than one.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen i've tried so many variants of making that class - i'm getting confused, and i'm afraid that something will not work after another one struct change. And about `self.master.destroy` - yes, i know that it's bad idea, just don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Your two classes do not represent `Tk` objects and do not use any of it's functionality, inheriting from `Tk` doesn't do anything in your code except potentially misleading the reader but it could cause larger issues if left alone. Removing `tk.Tk` from the class declaration won't break your code and will reduce the likelihood that it will break in the future so I highly recommend removing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would make sense to have a function that would handle the login action within `ApplicationWindow` that would then be passed over to `LoginWindow`, something like this:

```
class ApplicationWindow:
    ...
    def handle_login(self,name,passw):
        self.LOGIN = name
        self.PASSW = passw
        print("login was recieved from ApplicationWindow")
```

then you can pass it as an argument to `LoginWindow`:

```
class ApplicationWindow:
    ...
    def login(self):
        self.tl_log = tk.Toplevel(self.master)

        self.login = LoginWindow(self.tl_log, self.handle_login)
```

and store it as an instance variable for later use:

```
class LoginWindow():
    def __init__(self, master, login_action):
        self.successful_login_action = login_action
        ...
```

so instead of `return l,p` you would just call `self.successful_login_action(l,p)`:

```
class LoginWindow():
    ...
    def func(self):
        l = self.e_log.get()
        p = self.e_psw.get()
        if l == "" or " " in l:
            print("not")
        else:
            self.successful_login_action(l,p)
            #return l, p 
            self.master.destroy() #now this is called! Yay :)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll keep this moment in mind in further work with classes.